# addEventListener not attaching my function?

Tags: javascript

Below is my script. When I click one of the elements in question with the console open I do not see my data passed into the array "dataLayer'.

Is it to do with scope? Why does function `eventData()` not run on click of any of the elements in variable cta_btns?

```
<script>

  var cta_btns = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("a[href*='pricing']"));
  cta_btns.shift();
```

(cta_buttons is an array of links on the page)

```
  for ( var i=0; i<cta_btns.length; i++ ) {      
    if (document.addEventListener) { 
      cta_btns[i].addEventListener('click', eventData(), false); 
    } else if (document.attachEvent) { 
      cta_btns[i].attachEvent('on' + 'click', eventData()); 
    } 
  }


function eventData(e) {
  dataLayer.push({
      'event': 'home_cta',
      'iteration': 'hold',
      'gtm.element': e.target,
      'gtm.elementClasses': e.target.className || '',
      'gtm.elementId': e.target.id || '',
      'gtm.elementTarget': e.target.target || '',
      'gtm.elementUrl': e.target.href || e.target.action || '',
      'gtm.originalEvent': e
    });
}

</script>
```

Comment: Can you provide your code in CodePen?

Comment: Remove braces in `cta_btns[i].addEventListener('click', eventData(), false); `. Make it `cta_btns[i].addEventListener('click', eventData, false); `. You should pass a handler, but not call it.

Comment: `eventData()` -> `eventData`

Comment: on the overview when you want to use addEventListener and call a function that takes params it should be .addEventListener('click', function(){eventData(pass param here)}, false) but ya as requested by @MrBear providing code will help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling method instead of assigning it

Convert this

```
cta_btns[i].addEventListener('click', eventData(), false);
```

to this

```
cta_btns[i].addEventListener('click', eventData, false);
```

Same for

```
cta_btns[i].attachEvent('on' + 'click', eventData());
```

to this

```
cta_btns[i].attachEvent('on' + 'click', eventData);
```